# Create x instances of a class using while loop - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, while-loop, instance

I am looking to make *x* instances of a class based on a user's input.  Please take a quick glance at my code:

```
class Cut:
    def __init__(self, length, qty):
        self.length = length
        self.qty = qty

qty_cut_lengths = input("How many cutting lengths are there?")
cut_number = 1

while cut_number <= qty_cut_lengths:
    self.length = input("What is the length of " + cut_number + "?")
    self.qty = input("How many pieces will be needed?")
    cut_number += 1
```

e.g. If a user inputs *10*, I would like for the code to create 10 instances of the Cut class, each with the corresponding lengths and qtys.  So for the first cuts let's say the "customer" need 5 pieces of 30 inches of material.  I would want cut1.length = 30, cut1.qty = 5.  Then let's say they need 20 pieces of 15 inch material.  cut2.length = 15, cut2.qty = 20.  And so on...  I can't figure out a good way to make this happen.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: List comprehension.   `foos = [ Foo(x) for x in range(15)  ]`

Answer (score 0):

After taking in the length/quantity, create a new Cut

```
cut = new Cut(length, quantity)
```

and store them in a list

```
cuts = []
while (cut_number <= qty_cut_lengths):
    ... create cut as above...
    cuts.append(cut)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so far from the solution. You just need to create the instances, and to make some conversions:

```
class Cut:
    def __init__(self, length, qty):
        self.length = length
        self.qty = qty

qty_cut_lengths = input("How many cutting lengths are there?")
cuts=[]

for cut_number in range(int(qty_cut_lengths)):
    length = input("What is the length of cut n°" +str(cut_number+1)+"?")
    qty = input("How many pieces will be needed?")
    cuts.append(Cut(int(length),int(qty))) # instance creation and storage
```